# MyBatis Migrations: does "migrate new" automatically generate the changes?

Tags: sql, mybatis, database-migration

With the [migrate new](http://mybatis.github.io/migrations/new.html) command, it generates a sql file:

```
-- // create blog table
-- Migration SQL that makes the change goes here.

-- //@UNDO
-- SQL to undo the change goes here.
```

Does the command detect my table and data changes and fill in  with the script, such as Alter Table query, automatically? Or I have to fill in the scripts manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered [here](https://github.com/mybatis/migrations/issues/9):

> Migrations does not do any introspection or reverse engineering of
>   your database.   You have to enter the DDL changes your self.